# replace values in a pandas df column if they appear in another column

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to replace words in column `something` if they are the same as column `to_hide`. So I'd like to go from here

```
    to_hide                something
0       bla  there is bla over there
1       sth    i cannot see anything
2  sth else    sth else is beautiful
```

to here

```
  to_hide                    something
0       bla  there is to_hide over there
1       sth        i cannot see anything
2  sth else         to_hide is beautiful
```

The below unfortunately throws an error

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'to_hide':['bla','sth','sth else'], 'something':['there is bla over there','i cannot see anything','sth else is beautiful']})
df.assign(**{'something' : df['something'].str.replace(df['to_hide'], 'to_hide')})
```

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

how can I write it so it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a loop here:

```
df['something'] = [s.replace(pat, 'to_hide')
                   for pat, s in zip(df['to_hide'], df['something'])]
```

output (as new column for clarity):

```
    to_hide                something                   something2
0       bla  there is bla over there  there is to_hide over there
1       sth    i cannot see anything        i cannot see anything
2  sth else    sth else is beautiful         to_hide is beautiful
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative would be to go with `apply()`:

```
df['something'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.something.replace(x.to_hide, 'to_hide'), axis=1)
```

###### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'to_hide':['bla','sth','sth else'], 'something':['there is bla over there','i cannot see anything','sth else is beautiful']})
df['something'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.something.replace(x.to_hide, 'to_hide'), axis=1)
```

###### Output

|  | to_hide | something |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bla | there is to_hide over there |
| 1 | sth | i cannot see anything |
| 2 | sth else | to_hide is beautiful |

Comment: As a note, this is doing exactly the same a my [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913494/16343464) but much slower (e.g., on 30k items, `353 ms ± 11.2 ms` vs `6.52 ms ± 304 µs` for the list comprehension). Most of the time pure python will be faster than `apply` ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out - I try to check the speed as well for future answers.

Comment: @mozway : Now I'm curious, why is the speed difference so pronounced? apart from the fact that the `apply()` is done to the entire `dataframe`. Presumably you have some eminent experience here that made you think directly in the direction of `list comprehension`.

Comment: It's a well know fact in the pandas community. `apply` uses a Series at each step so there is an overhead of creating the Series for each iteration. In contrast the python loops uses the raw objects

Comment: Wow again, I wouldn't have guessed that. On the contrary, I assumed that this kind of process runs more optimally within pandas. but thanks to you, I'm a bit smarter now. Really good food for thought - I have enough input to delve deeper into the topic myself. Thank you